# How can I extract the date from a formula to another cell?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formulas

[screen capture of formula](http://goo.gl/KsdFd3)

This is for a Mathematics stock market project for our 8th grade students.

Is there any way that the date in the visible formula can be automatically copied from the formula and put into the adjacent cell? (As these are grade 8 students, we are trying to 'economize' as many steps as possible.)

Comment: Why aren't you putting *D5* where you have "*December 15, 2014"*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but E5 contains the google finance formula that includes the date of purchase [=min(GoogleFinance("ibm", "PRICE", "december 15, 2014")] I'd like somehow to automatically extract that date [February 15, 2014] and fill D5 (etc.) with it.

Comment: I just saw your comment, pnuts. I get it now. Makes sense. Thanks! Brian.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to the appropriate string using the TEXT function:

`=MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("IBM","PRICE",TEXT(D5,"mmmm d, yyyy")))`

Comment: When I enter this formula, I get: 2/9/2015     155.75 (plain text) or 6/3/1900 (formatted as date). I've clearly missed something, I'm sorry. From E5 [formula is: =min(GoogleFinance("ibm", "PRICE", "december 15, 2014")], I'd like to use a formula in D5 that, when entered, displays the date from the formula in E5. I'm very sorry for my lack of clarity, if that was the problem. I thank you for your patience.